# Displaying PHP variable in html

Tags: php, html

I have gotten to the point in my website development where I have a landing page. From this the user is prompted to login to their account. The login system is made using PHP. Now when the PHP redirects the user back to the landing page. I want there to be (yourname) displayed.
This is my PHP code declaring the username variable:

```
// variable declaration
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array(); 
$_SESSION['success'] = "";
```

Then on the landingpage.html I have this piece of code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<tr><td> <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" 
></td></tr>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Following this when I go onto the Landingpage.html site through localhost nothing is displayed. Any suggestions?

Comment: The typo in $username?

Comment: Use session variables to keep variables between different pages.

Comment: 1. Your input is hidden so it won't show up. 2. Your landingpage file probably needs to end in ".php" 3. Variables are not persisted between page loads, you need to pass the data somehow: cookie, session, url

Comment: whats up with the tr td but no table declaration? maybe paste your html into an HTML VALIDATOR, google it might be helpful. . .

Comment: On a side note: HTML content should be put *between* the `<body></body>` tags.

Comment: too many possible answers

Comment: and how are you passing that input? Your question is too broad and unclear. Your code appears incomplete. Btw, are you only responding to answers? You seem to be ignoring comments here. If that's the case, then you lost me; good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$username variable is now empty
you have to set some value for $username

```
$username = $_SESSION['success'];
```

then

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>Untitled Document</title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <tr><td> <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
      </td></tr>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

after the redirection (i.e. a new request) all your variables are unset again. If you want to save variables among requests, you have to use session-variables like $_SESSION['username']

Comment: also OP need to change file extension

Comment: unreleased. Thats the point. Im asking how can I display a php variable into a .html file. So why would I change the format of the file? That makes no sense,

Comment: @unreleased not necessarily.